# Excel Expand formulas based on the length of the list results

Tags: excel

I'm using the filter formula to return a list of results.  The length of rows of the list is variable.
For each returned value I need to apply a new formula.  I would like to know if I can extend this formula automatically all rows based on the length of the list.

A simple example:  On cells A1:B100 I have a list of values.  On Cell D1 I have this formula `=FILTER(A2:A10;B2:B10="Filter")`

The result will be a list in Colum D that can have 1 row and upto 100.
In Column E I need to have this formula `D1*10`.  This should extend to the rows below dynamicaly based on the number of rows returned on the Filter formula

Any ideas if this can be done automatically?

What I'm doing is quite more complex than this example since I'm filtering a table that is in a different workbook that is custom data type and the number of rows will vary from about 10 to over 9.000

Comment: Your question is not clear. `FILTER()` formula will automatically spill result what it return. If you want to make `Array` part dynamic then you have to use `INDIRECT()` formula.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [spilled range operator](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/spilled-range-operator-3dd5899f-bca2-4b9d-a172-3eae9ac22efd) `#` after the cell in question:

```
=D1#*10
```

[image]